# Add "carriage returns" (extra line) after all entries in document [examples added]

Tags: org-mode, newlines

I've noticed that Emacs will preserve an extra line (carriage return) between items, but if I manually edit the file, this extra spacing can fall apart. For example, I've found that entries need 2 spaces to have an additional line after them when collapsed, but I often don't add this extra space manually.

Are there any existing commands that would allow me to clean up the doc and ensure that all items have an extra line between them?

Consider the following examples when the tree is full expanded.

This is the desired spacing:

[image]

However, this is what I often end up with after editing the tree by hand. Notice the lack of extra line between Entry 2A + 3A

[image]

Comment: The question isn't very clear. What do you mean by "items" and "entries". Maybe show an example (text is better than images, but even screenshots could help).

Comment: Thanks @Drew — updated with examples to hopefully make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior depends on the value of the option `org-cycle-separator-lines`. The default value is 2, so you need at least two empty lines in order to have an empty line between the collapsed headings. I don't know of a built-in function to fix this, but it's easy enough to roll your own:

```el
#+begin_src elisp

  (defun my/org-ensure-two-empty-lines()
    (save-excursion
      (let (count)
        (outline-next-heading)
        (when (not (eobp))
          (setq count (abs (skip-chars-backward "\n")))
          (while (< count 3)
            (insert "\n")
            (setq count (+ 1 count)))))))

  (defun my/org-fix-cycle-separator-newlines ()
    (interactive)
    (org-map-entries #'my/org-ensure-two-empty-lines))

  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c z") #'my/org-fix-cycle-separator-newlines)

#+end_src
```

The "driver" function `my/org-fix-cycle-separator-newlines` calls the "worker" function `my/org-ensure-two-empty-lines` at every heading in the buffer (see the doc string of `org-map-entries` for how it works: it's a very versatile and powerful function). The worker function makes sure that there are at least three newlines before the next heading: two for empty lines and one for the final newline after the end of the text.
It does not add anything at the end of the buffer.

To test, you can add the code block above to your Org mode file (I usuallly add a `* Code  :noexport:` heading at the end of the file for testing code like this and add the code underneath it), modify the key binding if you don't like my choice of `C-c z` (this key tends to be unused, which is why I tend to choose it) and evaluate the code with `C-c C-c` in the code block. Then test by typing `C-c z` or whatever you changed that to. Assuming that it all works, you can copy the body of the whole block (sans `#+begin/end_src` lines) into your init file and you should be all set. If I were to move it to my init file, I would seriously think about a different keybinding: I like to leave `C-c z` free for testing code.

Comment: Thanks for such a thoughtful answer. Looking forward to testing this out :)